# Proper Design in Cloud Firestore Document Database

Tags: firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore, document-database

I'm a little new to NoSQL and I'm struggling to understand how to design the database when different documents have relationships. I've read a few articles on design patterns for NoSQL, but I seem to get conflicting information. Here is the situation I'm facing.

I have a collection of users and each user has a set of activities that they practice. It looks something like this:

```
[Collection] Users
  - [Doc] usr10343
     name: Bob
     age: 27
  - [Doc] usr19282
     name: Jenny
     age: 32

[Collection] Activities
  - [Doc] act19203
     name: Warmup Jog
     description: {...}
     duration: 10m
  - [Doc] act28301
     name: Burpies
     description: {...}
     duration: 8m
```

Now, the activities have the same name, duration, and description across all users, but there is extra user-specific data, like how many times they did that activity or when the last time was. I am creating a subcollection under each user for their activities, but I see two patterns for how to create it. Either duplicate all of the activity data so each doc in the subcollection looks like this:

```
   - [Doc] instance39201
     name: Warmup Jog
     description: {...}
     duration: 10m
     numberOfTimes: 8
     lastCompleted: 10/18/2017
```

which seems like a lot of duplication and a real hassle if I ever want to update the name or description. Or, I could use a reference like this:

```
   - [Doc] instance39201
     activity: act19203
     numberOfTimes: 8
     lastCompleted: 10/18/2017
```

And that feels like I am using a relational database without the benefit of SQL. Am I missing something. Is there a better way to approach this that I'm not finding? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There is not a "one true way" to model all data for all time in a nosql database.  Your modeling should suit the queries you intend to make on it.  If you don't know your queries, then you can't necessarily know an effective modeling.  It's all about efficacy.  A model isn't "right" if it doesn't suit the needs of your app.